# Overlay Div on image

Tags: html, css, overlay

So I have a `<div>` with relative positioning, and it has a child `<img>` with absolute positioning.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="image.png" style="position: absolute;" />
  <span id="overlay_text">OVERLAY</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that it needs to be at the top (higher on the Y axis, or closer to the top of the screen), but it is only measured in distance from the bottom.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: So you need the `<span>` to be on top of the `<img>`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371594/display-div-or-span-over-image-on-hover/21371665#21371665) it should do what you want.

Comment: by default, the `<img>` has `left: 0; top: 0` if no other CSS inherited. This acts as the same as no `position: absolute`. What exactly do you want? Does `z-index` or set the image to background image help ?

Answer (score 20):

Use `z-index` and `top`. This will layer the div on bottom, the image and then the span (overlay) on top. To set the positioning from the top edge, use `top`, which can be used with negative numbers if you need it to be higher on the Y axis than it's parent. The example below will move the span 10px above the top of it's parent div.

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
  <img src="image.png" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;" />
  <span id="overlay_text" style="position: relative; top: -10px; z-index: 3;">OVERLAY</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean top on the Y axis, as in higher on the screen, not on top of the image.  I will clarify above.

Answer (score 11):

This is in some cases a better solution, so the parent div gets height of the image:

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
  <img src="image.png" />
  <span style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 3;">OVERLAY</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me since with the other answers i lost height/width

Answer (score 6):

I'm aware this is an old question but I've noticed several examples using `z-index`, which may not be necessary for this use case and can become problematic with dozens of stacked elements.

N.B.: Elements are stacked from bottom to top. In this case:

`<span>OVERLAY</span>` is declared below `<img />`.
Therefore, `span` is stacked above `img`.

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Delta-shield.png" style="position: absolute;" />
  <span id="overlay_text" style="position: relative; top: 8rem; margin-left: 80px">OVERLAY</span>
</div>
```

More information on stacking can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index).

Comment: Thanks for keeping things simple (not using z-index)!