# CSS Transition - eases in but doesn't ease out?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a wee problem concerning my images, as shown here (http://jsfiddle.net/garethweaver/Y4Buy/1/).

```css
.img-blur:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vp5StNs.png" class="img-blur">
```

The image blurs when the mouse hovers but when I take my mouse off it goes straight back to normal, how can I make it ease out of the blur?

Also, is there a way to show text when the mouse hovers over? When the user hovers over the image I want it to blur and then show some text such as "Learn More". Is this also possible with just css?

Cheers

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Add the transition properties to the element itself rather than the `:hover` pseudo-class version.

In doing so, the transition will take place when hovering on ***and*** off.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jVdg2/)

```css
.img-blur {
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
.img-blur:hover {
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vp5StNs.png" class="img-blur" />
```

---

If you want different transition properties when hovering on/off, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uF5Xb/).

- The transition property on the element itself will take place when hovering **off** of the element.
- The transition on the `:hover` pseudo class will take place when hovering **on** the element:

```css
.img-blur {
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;   /* Hover off */
}
.img-blur:hover {
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
    transition: all 1s ease-in;         /* On hover */
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vp5StNs.png" class="img-blur">
```

---

If you want text to be added on hover, take a look at either of these past answers.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322705/2680216
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371665/2680216

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick comment, do you know how to add text when it is hovered over?

Comment: @Gareth I added in a couple of links. Hopefully they are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta remember you need to tell the computer what happens when it is not getting hovered over. Why you need to add a transition property into the class when its not getting hovered.

here is the CSS:

```
.nav__menuIcon--button {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}

.nav__menuIcon--button:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}
```